# Convert void* from array of shorts (short*) to array of floats (float) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a struct that contains a `void*` in this `void*` is an array of shorts (`short*`) eg `-6,-113, -110,...,n`

I would like to convert all of those wonderful shorts to floating point. eg `-6` --> `-6.0000000`

```
typedef struct datablock
{
  int maxRows;
  void *data;
} DataBlock;

// imagine *data points to a short* --> { -6, -113, -100, -126 }

static void Read(params here)
{
  float *floatData;
  data = (float *) DataBlock->data; // obvious fail here
  // data will now look like --> { -1.Q#DEN00, -1.Q#ENV00, ..., n} 
  // i assume the compiler is not handling the conversion for me
  // which is why the issue comes up
  // **NOTE** Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate is the enviorment (windows 8)
}
```

Comment: "*i assume the compiler is not handling the conversion for me*" it will. You however need to provide the appropriate amount of memory.

Comment: data = (float *) DataBlock->data; did you mean floatData = (float *) DataBlock->data?

Comment: Does your datablock data field have to be a void*, if not, it would be much clearer if the type were just short*.  Even if it's meant to point to multiple data types, you might make the void *data field actually a union of different pointer types to express that intent in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct datablock
{
  int maxRows;
  void *data;
} DataBlock;

[...]

  DataBlock db = ... <some init with shorts>;

  DataBlock db_f = {db.maxRows, NULL};
  db_f.data = malloc(db_f.maxRows * sizeof(float));
  /* Add error checking here. */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < db_f.maxRows; ++i)
  {
    *(((float *) db_f.data) + i)  = *(((short *) db.data) + i);
  }

  /* Use db_f here. */

  free(db_d.data); /* Always tidy up before leaving ... */
```

As proposed by *[Sylvain Defresne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353/sylvain-defresne)* the body of the loop is easiser to read using temporary pointers:

```
  for (
    size_t i = 0, 
    short * src = db.data,
    float * dst = db_f.data;
    i < db_f.maxRows; 
    ++i)
  {
    dst[i] = src[i];
  }
```

Comment: You could introduce temporary pointers `short* src = (short*)db.data;` and `float* dst = (float*)db_f.data;` then, the inner loop will be easier to read: `dst[i] = (float)src[i];`.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks! @VisaisRacism

Comment: @SylvainDefresne, there is no need for the cast to `float`. Since you are assigning to a `float`, it gets cast anyway.

Comment: @VisaisRacism yeah, the cast is not necessary, I'm just too used to compiling with `-Wconversion` and `-Werror`, that I just insert those explicit cast to avoid compilation failures.

Comment: @SylvainDefresne: `-Wconversion` won't warn here. The code is perfectly valid without casting. Note that this is different from C++.

Comment: @VisaisRacism: "*... it gets cast anyway.*" Not quiet right. It gets implicitly "*converted*". A cast is always explicit.

Comment: @alk yeah, you're right, conversion from `short` to `float` cannot cause data loss, so `-Wconversion` won't warn. I stand corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @alk, sorry I may have not been precise with the wording.